# Reading file in C++ through ifstream object

Tags: c++

I have a program written for reading files using ifstream object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


struct FPlayerInfo
{
    string name;
    string pos;
    int numTouchDowns;
    int numCatches;
    int numPassingYards;
    int numReceivingYards;
    int numRushingYards;
};


void loadInfo(FPlayerInfo info[10], string filename)
{
    int i=0;
    ifstream ifs(filename.c_str() , ios::in);

    if (ifs.good() && ifs.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        while (getline(ifs, line))
        {
            ifs >> info[i].name >> info[i].pos >> info[i].numTouchDowns >> info[i].numCatches >> info[i].numPassingYards 
                >> info[i].numReceivingYards >> info[i].numRushingYards;

            cout << info[i].name << endl;
            i++;
        }

        ifs.close();
    }
}

int main()
{
    FPlayerInfo info[10];

    loadInfo(info , "Footballdata.txt"); 

    return 0;  
}
```

The Footballdata.txt contains the following data:

```
Bill Quarter_Back 70 0 8754 0 573
Jackson Receiver 55 87 50 5490 574
Grahm Running_Back 45 30 0 50 2800
McCoy Full_Back 25 10 0 25 3762
Daryl Quarter_Back 50 2 7560 0 450
Santiago Left_Tackle 5 0 0 0 0
Hanks Receiver 35 37 0 3590 876
Johnson Running_Back 25 80 0 100 4000
Miller Receiver 110 250 150 7867 2100
Ruth Quarter_Back 85 0 12901 0 3249
```

After execution of the above program, I expect all the names to be returned in the output. But What I observed is that the first name is missing in the actual output and last line I am getting blank. Can anyone please tell me where I am making mistake while reading the file ?

Thanks in advance.

**Actual Output:**

```
Jackson
Grahm
McCoy
Daryl
Santiago
Hanks
Johnson
Miller
Ruth
```

Comment: No , its not like that , only first line is missing.

Comment: Yes, `>>` will leave an end-of-line in the input buffer that `getline` reads for the following lines. However, using the `getline` is still wrong. You could do just `while (ifs >> etc`.

Comment: @BoPersson, How will I know about the end of file ? Can you tell me complete statement in while loop ?

Comment: A bit ugly, but you can put the entire input line inside the `while()`. It will return true if all the input worked and false when it fails. (Assuming that end of file is the only place where input fails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getline` reads a line from the input
and then `ifs >> info[i].name >> ..` reads additional info thus skipping what you have read using `getline`.

Simply change:

```
string line;
while (getline(ifs, line))
{
    ifs >> info[i].name >> info[i].pos >> info[i].numTouchDowns >> info[i].numCatches >> info[i].numPassingYards 
        >> info[i].numReceivingYards >> info[i].numRushingYards;
    [..]
}
```

Into:

```
while (true)
{
    ifs >> info[i].name >> info[i].pos >> info[i].numTouchDowns >> info[i].numCatches >> info[i].numPassingYards 
        >> info[i].numReceivingYards >> info[i].numRushingYards;
    if (!ifs) break;
    [..]
}
```

An **better implementation** (splitted to avoid littering the actual issue), is using a temp object and moving it once we realized the read was successful:

```
while (true)
{
    FPlayerInfo temp;
    ifs >> temp.name >> temp.pos >> temp.numTouchDowns >> temp.numCatches >> temp.numPassingYards 
        >> temp.numReceivingYards >> temp.numRushingYards;
    if (!ifs) break;

    info[i] = std::move(temp);
    [..]
}
```

Comment: Getting some garbage values at the end though it is reading the first line now.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, added an improvement recommendation, please take a look :)